# Basic Arduino Airplane Control

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, servo

I have a task where I need to control the airplanes thrust and altitude direction(Up-Down). For the thrust I thought of using a DC Motor and a Servo for the other. Control of servo will be from the buttons and the thrust value will be given from the serial port. (This is not a project of a real vehicle, only thing I need to do is the code, rest is imaginary.)
[image]

I have wrote the following code. I would like to ask is there any flaws and how can I further improve it? Thanks in advance.
With my regards...

```
#include <Servo.h>
  Servo servo1;
  int pos = 0;
  const int buttonSUP = 2;
  const int buttonSDOWN = 3;

  int buttonStateUP = 0;
  int buttonStateDOWN = 0;


  int motorPin = 4;

  void setup() {

  servo1.attach(9);
  pinMode( buttonSUP, INPUT); 
  pinMode( buttonSDOWN, INPUT); 

  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (! Serial);
    Serial.println("Speed 0 to 255");

  }

  void loop() {
   buttonStateUP =digitalRead(buttonSUP);
   if(buttonStateUP=HIGH){
      servo1.write(90);    
      Serial.println("UP");                            
    } 
    if(buttonStateDOWN=HIGH){
      servo1.write(0); 
     Serial.println("DOWN");  
      }
    else{
        servo1.write(45);
        Serial.println("STABLE");  
        }    

    if (Serial.available())
    {
      int speed = Serial.parseInt();
      if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 255)
      {
        analogWrite(motorPin, speed);
        Serial.println(speed);  
      }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Your formatting is off, but also, it's always either DOWN or STABLE?

Comment: I thought as the servo being 45 degrees shifted just as  this "<". There fore with a 90 degree move, I can shift from up to down or vice versa .

Answer (score 0):

`while (! Serial);`  Is not needed if you have a board with USB-> Serial bridge Chip (arduino uno for example)

```
if(buttonStateDOWN=HIGH){
}
```

In every condition you used `=` instead of `==`. Your "condition" actually assigns `HIGH` to `buttonStateDOWN`. If you want to compare integers, use `==`.

And according to the question, I think you have misunderstood the speed buttons (or maybe I have). I think, they want you to code it so while the button is pressed or every time the button is pressed, the speed changes by +1 or -1.

Assuming the rest works fine, there could be a problem with your serial output, since you just spam messages.

Read about the `millis();`, it can help you so you only send something every x amount of seconds, without using `delay();` [Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=503368.0)